# shares on a post using facebook4j

Tags: facebook, post, restfb

Please help me with this. Is it possible to get the id and names of people who shared a facebook post using facebook4j? Restfb has following method:
    getShares(); 
but this returns null. Facebook4j has function:
    getSharesCount();
Is there no way to get the names of people who shared a post using facebook4j or restfb

Comment: No, there is not. You get information only about people that are using your app, not about others.

Comment: Have you tried the `sharedposts` edge? Perhaps you can get some information from there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/sharedposts

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the post ID you can make this ajax call.

https://www.facebook.com/ajax/pagelet/generic.php/ViewSharesPagelet?data{"load":0,"target_fbid":POST ID}&__a=1

You can then download this or read the response.

The shared page has infinite scrolling so you can just increment "load:0" to get the rest of the names